# Is derivative a finite function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

we define
$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0}(f_{x+dx}-f_{x})/a = df/dx$
Does $a\rightarrow 0$ mean $(f_{x+dx}-f_{x})\rightarrow0$?
If this is true then 0/0 gives you a finite function i.e. df/dx. 
How is it?

Comment: Are you asking how it is possible that a limit that goes toward $\frac00$ has a finite value?

Comment: If you are talking about derivatives, shouldn't the $a$ be d$x$?

Comment: Do you not know what "limits" are?  Are you actually taking a Calculus class or did you just happen to find that somewhere in a book?

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ is an indeterminate form. It doesn't mean that it is undefined necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a rather strange notation (mixing $a$ and $dx$?), it would make more sense as:
$$\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}$$
More often you see $h$ instead of $a$ or sometimes $\Delta x$.

In any case, you are correct that both the numerator and the denominator have limit $0$ so direct substitution gives you the indeterminate form "$\tfrac{0}{0}$". The limit however can still have finite value, but this is not necessarily the case. When the limit exists, we say that $f$ is *differentiable* (at $x$).